# Can we use the regular value theorem to show that the graph of a smooth map between two smooth manifolds is a submanifold of the product?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $f: M \to N$ be differentiable. Show that the graph $G:=\{(q, f(q))\mid q \in M\}$ is a submanifold of $M\times N$. Here $M \times N$ carries the product topology.

I was wondering is there any way to show this with the help of the regular value theorem? I know in the case of mappings from $R^m \to R^n$, the regular value theorem is very useful, but I am not sure about the general case between abstract smooth manifolds whether the regular value theorem has any use or should be used at all.

Comment: Sure. Write this in the obvious way as a zero set.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was thinking the same as you, but then it came to my mind that there is no "zero" neither "substraction" in $M$ or $N$ and then had a doubt. What's in your mind?

Comment: @TedShifrin, yeah I also thought of this, but we can't subtract because there is no such thing as addition or subtraction or 0 in abstract manifolds. That is why I was wondering whether the RVT can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in taking one step further than the Regular Value Theorem. If $\Phi\colon X\to Y$ is transverse to a submanifold $Z\subset Y$, then $\Phi^{-1}(Z)$ is a submanifold of $X$. (This is proved by reducing to the Regular Value Theorem.)

In this case, use the "diagonal trick." Define $G\colon M\times N\to N\times N$ by $\Phi(x,y) = (f(x),y)$. You can easily check that (completely independent of the mapping $f$) $\Phi$ is transverse to the diagonal $\Delta \subset N\times N$ and $\Phi^{-1}(\Delta) = G$, as desired.